# Does Mozilla Firefox automatically delete old history entries?

Tags: firefox, browser, history

I've recently done a little experiment and took a look at the first few websites which I have ever visited with my current Firefox profile and wrote them down. I was also a little bit confused, because I don't think that the things I apparently first ever visited in the Firefox history viewer were actually what I first ever visited.

A month or so later, I took another look at the first few websites I visited in the Firefox history viewer, but they were something completely different this time.

I'm very confused as to why this happens. Does Firefox automatically delete history entries which have a certain age?

For clarification:

Yes, I did click "Older than 6 months", and yes, I am also aware that history entries, which I visit again in the future automatically get moved to the top of the history list. I have also entered the URLs that I wrote down in the search box, but no results. So I assume Firefox deletes history?

EDIT: And if the answer is yes, is there a way to make it so that Firefox never deletes history entries? (I know it affects performance, but I'd rather keep all of my history entries permanently)

Comment: Yes, it does. I think this is configurable in about:config.

Comment: Go to about:config. Read and accept the warning, then find "browser.history_expire_days.mirror". I don't keep history that old, but depending what it is set on, you could try setting it to something >180 days. Don't know if there is an upper limit though.

Comment: @user3169 that pref is obsolete for a few years now...

Comment: I have a backup of `places.sqlite` from two different points in time, one year apart, and they are both `83,886,080` bytes in size (exactly 80 MB), so yeah.. it seems so >.<

Comment: If you want to deleted your question, flag it for moderators attention. But do not vandalize it as [you just did](https://superuser.com/posts/1054833/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

Moderators at Mozilla suggested the [following](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1148703#answer-941077):

> You would have to create a new integer pref with the name
>   `places.history.expiration.max_pages` and set the value of the pref to
>   the desired number of history items like you can see in my post above.
>   Preferences can be created on the about:config page via the
>   right-click context menu: New -> Integer

Comment: I've written a technical post on this here: https://superuser.com/a/1405880/153095 (In summary: some history entries will be removed even when this setting is used)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is only one setting in about:config that seems to control this:
`places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages`. On my machine it's set to 104858 (it says 'user set', but i have never and seem to be unable to change it's value). Interestingly in practice, that amounts to less than 6 months!!!
according to [this blog entry](http://bonardo.net/mozilla/2012/02/13/places-got-async-expiration.html) it's supposedly all my machine can handle (sure skylake, 32gb ram & 1tb ssd can't handle more ;-))...

Assuming each history entry takes about 100 bytes (average page title + url + visited timestamp + visit counter (in my case)) that caps history at about 10MB, but i'd rather it taking 10GB and retaining more than 5 years...

real shame as this essentially makes firefox much worse than i ever thought it was...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will act based on the setting set in Privacy (copy/paste this in the location bar `about:preferences#privacy`)

From the `History`, spot `Firefox will` and choose `Remember history` from the drop-down list. This should keep your browsing activities.

From the `Location Bar`, tick a mark in `History`. This should display visited URLs when your typing matches an entry in the History.

Comment: if it forgets all history, it only means that someone has cleared it.